# Search word and job title in database is same but not getting

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have job portal website. In that when user search some work then we are matching that word with job title in database and displaying the result. 
The problem is Ex. when user searches the word 'Php Developer'. we are matching that word in database with job_title and displying exact matched results. In my database job_title contains exact word 'Php Developer' but results coming as empty.

```
SELECT *  FROM `tbl_jobs` WHERE `job_title` = 'Php Developer' or `job_title` like 'Php Developer'.
```

The database contains exact title records but they do not appear when I search as in the query above.

I am getting the results for this query.

```
SELECT *  FROM `tbl_jobs` WHERE `job_title` like '%Php Developer%'
```

My intention is exact word results. But I am not getting that to work. 
Please help me; where is my problem?

Comment: Don't you have any spaces before or after the value in the database? Are you sure you type the exact string (even capitals)

Comment: Is it just a problem with wild cards? 
%Php%Developer%

Comment: no . no spaces. i was copied the data from job_title column and searched that word. But Not get any results

Comment: Try this:  `SELECT REPLACE(job_title,' ','#'), * FROM tbl_jobs WHERE job_title like '%Php Developer%' `  That will make it clear if you have spaces in your column.

Comment: remove the spaces in tbl_jobs table UPDATE `tbl_jobs` SET `job_title` = TRIM( `job_title` )